# Tensorflow Serving: Need to make HTTP request to TF Server which accepts only gRPC requests

Tags: http, tensorflow, deep-learning, grpc, tensorflow-serving

My client is on a server where I can make only HTTP request to any server. The Tensorflow is hosted in an AWS machine which accepts the only gRPC requests. Looking for some leads to make this communication happen?

EDIT: 12 th June 2018

TF officially releases REST API for serving

https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest

They use this particular example: [half_plus_three](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_three/00000123)

Server:

`$ tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 \
   --model_name=half_plus_three \
   --model_base_path=$(pwd)/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_three/`

Client:

`$ curl -d '{"instances": [1.0,2.0,5.0]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_three:predict
{
    "predictions": [3.5, 4.0, 5.5]
}`

Comment: did you successfully work with the REST API? I'm running on an AWS instance with tensorflow 1.8 but tensorflow-model-server doesn't recognize "--rest_api_port"

Answer (score 0):

Which language/platform is your server running?

OTOH, TF is adding REST support now.